# Get FCM Notification Message and show it in separate Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get the push notification message that I sent to my app from firebase console to show it in separated activity (`MessageActivity`). When the user click on the received notification, the `MessageActivity` should be launched and show that message from notification.

one little thing: the message would contain URL how could I get url from text to show a buton in `MessageActivity` that would redirect user to that url (like if I published a new version).

Comment: If it's  an Activity so damn sure you have some inflator with "TextView" entity and set a properties "android:autoLink="web" that make your text clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set intent while you set notification builder like this

```
 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.notification1);
    mp.start();

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("MessageActivity")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```